# Catching Pop Unders with CasperJS and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using CasperJS and PhantomJS to do some web scraping and I want to try and capture Pop Unders when they happen on sites. Such as advertisements, etc.

I know there is a `WaitforPopup` function but this doesn't seem to behave the way I need it and doesn't trigger on Pop Unders. I've tried tons of things with the Popup functions but they seems to only work when a `target="_blank"` is clicked and not when an advertisement pops on a website due to javascript or something.

Has anyone had experience with this?

Any help or a push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Popups in CasperJS are the equivalent to additional windows in desktop browsers. Do you have that or are you talking about modals?

Comment: in this case a popunder could either be a new browser window or a new tab.

Comment: Which is the same thing in PhantomJS and should be available as popup.  Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.